# Ebubuntu in elementary OS

Tags: ubuntu

Can we install edubuntu tools  in elemaentry OS by typing sudo apt-get install ubuntu-edu-secondary ? will the system crash?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package in question using the command line as it is available in eOS without having to add any additional repos.

So far as crashes, I installed the package on an install of Loki running on a virtual machine and played around with it for a while and had no ill effects with the OS whatsoever. The Potato Guy app was cool! I also screwed around with the Pencil app and a couple others.

Lastly, depending upon your machine and speed of your internet connection, there was a large number of packages downloaded and installed which took some time to accomplish. If you have a slow connection, count on having time for a coffee break!

Good Luck!!!

P.S.-Before I installed the above, I had installed the 'software-properties-common' package as I had to do that before installing elementary Tweaks as well as some other apps. You may need to do so as well.